# Use logic to exit loop (instead of sys.exit, quit, assert, etc)

Tags: python, if-statement, logic, exit

Beginner here... Python 101

I have a list of if-else statements and need them to stop if the user enters a number outside a predefined range. But I can't use the quit/assert/sys.exit command to stop the program.  What is the 'logic' way to exit a command?

Ex: how would i use logic to exit this if statement (4 other separate statements follow it)?

```
    input_miles = float(input('Enter miles here: '))
    if input_miles >= 0:
        miles2km = input_miles*1.6
        print(input_miles, 'miles equal to', miles2km, 'km.')
    elif input_miles <0:
        assert FALSE
```

I am trying to check this box...
"If the user enters an invalid value, then the program will issue an error message and terminate immediately."

I know it's a basic question, but your help is greatly appreciated.

Updated for larger example:
miles to kilometers 1:1.6

```
    input_miles = float(input('Enter miles here: '))
    if input_miles >= 0:
        miles2km = input_miles*1.6
        print(input_miles, 'miles is equal to', miles2km, 'km. Wow!')
    elif input_miles <0:
        assert FALSE
```

Far to Celsius (F - 32)(5/9)

```
input_FarTemp = float(input())
    if input_FarTemp <= 1000:
        print('That\'s in Fahrenheit, let\'s convert that into Celsius')
        Far2Cel = ((input_FarTemp-32.0)*5/9)
        print(input_FarTemp, 'Fahrenheit is',Far2Cel, 'degrees Celsius')

    elif input_FarTemp > 1000:
        assert FALSE
```

Comment: You need to give us more context. This is probably in a function, so just return. Otherwise, I don't understand what the real issue is here. What do you want no to execute in which circumstances?

Comment: If you're in a function, you can return from it. If you're in a loop, you can `break` out of it. If not, then use `exit` when you want the program to exit.

Comment: raise an exception?

Comment: If you're saying "once I reach the end of my `if` block, I want to skip over all of the following elif and else blocks," you don't need to do anything special to do that. elif and else blocks are skipped automatically if the if's condition was satisfied.

Comment: Its a group of if functions.  I want it to run through one function, then if it doesn't meet that criteria, to quit before going to the next.  Let me add more of an example